# Will lots of small sql statements slow my site down significantly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zen-cart

I have a zen-cart with 25-30 categories. On the front page of the site each category will get it's own little area in which the 4 best selling products in that category will be displayed.

Being a bit of a noob the best way I can think of doing this is to have a single sql statement for each category which picks out the best sellers each time the page loads. I've read somewhere that you're best to limit the amount of sql statements so as not to affect site speed.

Would doing it this way be very much slower?

Is there a more sensible way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you do that with a more complex query? how's the schema?

Comment: As usual, the answer to this is 'it depends'. The best way to answer it if you have a working site is to make some changes and see what effect they have. Firstly I would get some HTML fragment caching on the go, as this will give you a huge win (better than any query) and then after that, try some SQL changes. In general, for simple queries, it is a good idea to limit the number of individual queries, so one query that gets four rows is often better that four seperate queries.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you can achieve the same thing with a single query that multiple queries will achieve, use the single query. There are exceptions to this, but they are few and far between. If you have something *really* complex, or something that involves/requires one or more MySQL UDFs, then there *may* be a case for separating it into multiple queries. In general less queries is better, because of the added overhead involved in sending the query/DB parsing it/DB finding the results/DB returning them/PHP parsing the result set. If you only use one query, all this only happens once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, the database schema is: http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Developers_-_Database_Schema but I've no idea how I would go about restricting the results for each category. @halfer I'll have to go off and google about html fragment caching coz I don't know what that is but it sounds useful :)

Comment: HTML caching -> it's basically generating a snippet of HTML (like best seller information and their image tags) from a database, and then using that snippet automatically for a preset time (say, the next 12 hours, since best-seller stuff doesn't change all that often). You can use the local file system for this, or memcache to get it nice and quick. I don't know [this module](http://www.magneticone.com/store/Zen.Cart.Modules/Zen.Cart.Performance.module), but it sounds good.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll have a look at that mod - shame it's not a free one though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That highly depends on the server backing your website. But 25 to 30 queries shouldn't have a major impact on the page performance.

A better way would be to design a database query that fetches all the items with one query. But to help you doing so we'd need the schema of your database.

Also in case you have to do many similar queries there is the options to use "prepared queries" that usually speed up the performance a good bit.

After all generally speaking, if you are new to working with database, its often better to design a few more small queries that are easily structures and can be handled by you, then one large query that has the potential to contain errors and maybe slows the database down more then then multiple small queries.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, the DB schema can be seen here: http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Developers_-_Database_Schema - does it look like it is going to be possible?!?

Comment: I am pretty confident that it is possible. If you tell me the query you are using now to find out the product to display from a single category, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hey there, thanks again. I don't actually have a query as of yet, I was trying to find out if this is all possible first! I'm a bit of a learner driver as far as sql goes.